# permutations of bst , given preorder array

Tags: binary-search-tree, permutation, preorder

Given a Preorder array of a Binary Search Tree how many other permutations of the given binary search tree will form the same BST as the given preorder.

Comment: Any attempt? Any research done? What if there are duplicate values?

Comment: Yes . No duplicates allowed

Comment: Please show your attempt and research efforts, and focus your question on where you got stuck.

Comment: BTW, I understand permutations of a (preorder) array, but can you explain what "permutations of the given binary search tree" means?

Comment: Permutations here means different possible structures of bst

Comment: Then what do you mean with the *same* BST? Surely if a BST has a different structure, it is not the same BST, right?

Comment: I suppose the question should read *"how many other BSTs have the same preorder sequence"*.

Answer (score 0):

First of a all: a value in a preorder sequence can never become an ancestor node of a node that has a value that occurred *earlier* in that sequence (this would be a contradiction with "preorder"). Any next value in the sequence (except the first) represents a child node of an earlier value's node. So values that are added to a tree are always leaves at the moment they are added -- never internal nodes.

The preorder sequence starts with the root, so any BST that it represents, must have it as root.

Any next value must be added as a leaf. So for the second value in the sequence there are 2 potential positions for it. For the 3rd, 3, for the 4th 4, ...etc. However, since the partial tree formed by the first k values must be a BST, there is only one of these positions for the unique (k+1)<sup>th</sup> value that is in line with the BST requirement, so there is never a choice between multiple alternatives.

By induction that means that only one BST can be formed from a preorder sequence of unique values.